# double fence and easement issues

Tags: fence

Both my neighbor and I have a fence, parallel to each other, at the back of our houses, with little space between them. My fence needs repair. What is the best way going forward?

Some posts are leaning and the runner is broken in a couple of spots. A partial repair is possible but probably won't look nice.

Does it make sense for me to come into my property by a foot and leave that space between the two fences? Perhaps adding a gate so that I can go between the fences and do periodic clean up of brush etc.

There is a power line about fence, and ATT line crossing the fence underground and mostly at least two feet away.

Fence is about 90 feet by 8 feet. What is a reasonable replacement cost?

Comment: This seems like a needless waste of resources where only one fence is actually needed...

Answer (score 1):

My locale requires a minimum 6" set back from property lines for fences; check with your local building regulations and verify that a foot meets or exceeds the easement.

What makes sense to me is for neighbors to split the cost of a fence and be cool about it. If you want to tie into their fence and it is decent shape, get an agreement written up and pay them a fair price. If you can't work something out with your neighbor, then it does make sense to set it back a bit and create a gate so you can clean it out.

Cost is off topic here and it is too broad of a question. Check with two or three local builders and pick the one you like best.